# get end date from start date and duration

Tags: date, cakephp, fullcalendar, cakephp-2.6

Situation is PHPCAKE 2.6 and Full Calendar plugin.
I need to fill end date based on start date + duration. The user must select start date and "visit type" list field.
Duration value is in hours and came from "visit_type_id" table, "duration" field

Any suggestion? Thanks in advance!

My form in add.ctp is:

```
echo $this->Form->input('visit_type_id', array(
    'label' => 'Tipo Visita',
));

echo $this->Form->input('start', array(
    'label' => 'Inizio',
    'dateFormat' => 'DMY',
    'timeFormat' => '24',
    'interval' => 15,
    'minYear' => 2015,
));

echo $this->Form->input('end', array(
    'type'=>'hidden',
));
```

Comment: it can be done using fullcalendar `format` function and also mention the version of fullcalendar

Comment: Thanks for reply! I'm using silasmontgomery plugin (https://github.com/silasmontgomery/CakePHP-Full-Calendar-Plugin), no idea which version is it. Can you write me down a little example how to get "duration", add to start and print end time? I'm very new with php cake...

Comment: Did you made some changes to plugin file ? if yes than undo it and try to run it simple as it is being provided. My suggestion don't use this plugin its outdated and unmaintained. Its using jQuery1.5 and fullcalendar 1.4, way too old. Try to do it yourself (from scrap) people at stack are there to help you every step of the way.

Comment: Ok. I'll try to integrate full calendar in my project by myself. Any tutorial or valid help out there to read for?

Comment: http://fullcalendar.io (download the whole package examples are in the same) && http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog/blog.html (complete the blog tutorial to get an better hold)

Comment: @valarmorghulis moved my issue here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30174077/full-calendar-and-cakephp-integration

Answer (score 0):

If the end date should change after the user updated the start date you will have to employ JavaScript (e.g.jquery) to update the end date onChange of the start date.

Comment: Sure is it... but I'm stuck with getting the end value!

Comment: What do you mean by that? You don't get the information from your form into the controller? Or you cannot set the end date?

Comment: I dont know how to set end time based on duration. I guess the line to change is $end = $event['Event']['end'];

Comment: If I understand your problem correctly you will need a JavaScript to read the startdate and the duration (you could store it in another hidden field) and calculate the resulting end date in Javascript and set the value of the end field by javaScript, too. 
But please don't ask me to deivier the code JavaScript is something I try to avoid as best as I can.